# Can i make make multiple beans for the same object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am learning how to work with the spring framework as part of my curriculum and I came across a strange situation concerning spring beans. I have a simple web project with a separate domain project. The domain contains a main service class called (surprise!) `MainService` which implements several service interfaces. I would now like to make several beans in the `applicationContext.xml` file of the web project, one for each interface, but I want each bean to instantiate as the same `MainService` object. I do not know whether this is possible in spring and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way round :
You create one bean of type MainService which implements interfaces A,B,C

If you need access to that instance you can just autowire the class or interface you want to use :

```
@Autowired MainService mainService;
@Autowired A a;
@Autowired B b;
@Autowired C c;
```

Creating many beans for the same instance might work somehow, but I wouldnt recomand it, it just does not make sense.